# Jquery Datatables breaks when using on same page with Data List

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datatable, webforms, datalist

I am using Jquery datatables on the same page with a data list. Both are populated server side. The datatables works great if I place the code above the data list. However, when placed below the data list, the datatables loses it's formatting/style and throws an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined" in the console. This is using ASP.NET Webforms.

```
            <asp:DataList ID="DataList" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Title").ToString()) ? true : false %>'>
                        <tr id="">
                            <td style="width: 171px">Title:</td>
                            <td style="width: 220px">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder2" runat="server" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("FirstName").ToString()) ? true : false %>'>
                        <tr id="">
                            <td style="width: 171px">First Name:</td>
                            <td style="width: 220px">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder3" runat="server" Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("MiddleName").ToString()) ? true : false %>'>
                        <tr id="">
                            <td style="width: 171px">Middle Name:</td>
                            <td style="width: 220px">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("MiddleName") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </asp:PlaceHolder>  
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
            <hr />

            <h6>DataTable:</h6>

            <asp:GridView ID="tblNotes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped dataTables_scrollHead">

                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CREATEDATE" HeaderText="Created Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CREATEDBY" HeaderText="Created By" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MODIFIEDDATE" HeaderText="Modified Date" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="MODIFIEDBY" HeaderText="Modified By" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Here's the Jquery:

```
$("[id*=tblNotes]").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "lengthChange": true,
        "searching": true,
        "ordering": true,
        "info": true,
        "autoWidth": true,
        "responsive": true,
        "dom": 'lBfrtip',
        "buttons": ['excel', 'print', 'pdfHtml5']
```

It's important that the DataTables be placed below the Datalist without losing formatting/style.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `DataList` renders an incomplete `table`. So when you place the DataList above the GridView, you get the following in html

```
<tr id="">
    <td style="width: 171px">Title:</td>
    <td style="width: 220px">
        <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<hr />

<h6>DataTable:</h6>
<table> GridView Contents </table>
```

The problem is that the next table, the GridView is not inside a `<td>` of the parent table, or is preceeded by a closing of the previous one. So unless you forgot to post the opening and closing `table` tags of the DataList that is probably the problem.
The reason it works the other way around is because a complete table is found that datatables.net can handle.

Comment: How would I place the GridView inside a <td> of the parent table as you suggested? Would this go inside the Jquery?

Comment: Basically you have to make sure the html is correct. Then it will work.

Comment: Removing all HTML inside <asp:DataList ID="DataList" runat="server"></asp:DataList> still gave same results as DataList creates it's own table tags. I found a solution by removing the DataList all together and using <asp:Repeater ID="DataList" runat="server"> instead.